# dynamic routing in sinatra based on request domain

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Lets say I have a modular Sinatra app being used for a hundred sites, that I need to conditionally pull in routes for - if the request.host is example.com then I want to register the routes in file `example_routes.rb` - but if the request.host is say, `other_example.com`, then I want to register another set of routes completely, ignoring the first file completely.

One could also argue the app is trying to do too many things, but for the sake of this discussion, I'd love to hear some ideas and approaches.

Unfortunately, it appears that by the time the request object comes through (which is needed to register the new routes), that routes can no longer be registered. This is the nature of my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you’ve noticed, you can’t define routes based on a request since they are all setup at startup before the first request comes in.

One way to achieve what you’re after could be to make use of the [`:host_name` condition](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Conditions):

```
get 'a_route', :host_name => 'example.com' do
  # this route will only apply to requests to example.com
end

get 'a_route', :host_name => 'other_example.com' do
  # this route will only apply to requests to other_example.com
end
```

These can be in different files if you want, and they won’t override each other so you can call them both at startup and requests will be routed to the appropriate code. Development and testing may be tricky, you may need to work out some way of accessing all routes locally.

Comment: this is very helpful but I will be using the same app for hundreds of domains :( - ultimately, i will be basing the route switch on a condition that comes back from a unique attribute for each domain object